# What does git diff mean by `[--]`

Tags: git, diff, byte-order-mark

I understand that the command below shows all changes, even whitespace changes. I know that the red `[--]` indicates something was deleted. But what space was deleted and should I fix it somehow. I'm trying to fix whitespace, particularly line ending, inconsistencies among the MSYS, PowerShell, and Linux environments.

```
$ git diff --color --word-diff-regex=. -- Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
diff --git a/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs b/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
index 7518832..3621c0b 100644
--- a/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
+++ b/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
[--]using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
@@ -64,7 +64,7 @@ namespace Althing.Pages
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(28);[-^M-]
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By copy-pasting your diff into [`uniname`](https://billposer.org/Software/unidesc.html), I obtained this:

```
$ printf '[-﻿-]' | uniname
character  byte       UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
        0          0  00005B   5B             [      LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
        1          1  00002D   2D             -      HYPHEN-MINUS
        2          2  00FEFF   EF BB BF               ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
        3          5  00002D   2D             -      HYPHEN-MINUS
        4          6  00005D   5D             ]      RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
```

The removed character is U+FEFF ZERO-WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, also known as the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It's an invisible character whose purpose is to indicate the encoding of the file it appears in. It's not recommended in UTF-8 text, but sometimes appears there anyway.

Comment: This appeared after I changed line ending encodings from `dos` to `unix` in Emacs, so that makes sense.

Comment: Line ending encodings (CR+LF vs LF) are a matter separate from the BOM.